# How to remove all NAs in character strings in a dataframe column in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file like

```
LocationList,Identity,Category
"New York,New York,United States","42","S"
"NA,California,United States","89","lyt"
"Hartford,Connecticut,United States","879","polo"
"San Diego,California,United States","45454","utyr"
"Seattle,Washington,United States","uytr","69"
"NA,NA,United States","87","tree"
```

I want to remove all 'NA' from the 'LocationList' Column

The Desired Result -

```
 LocationList,Identity,Category
"New York,New York,United States","42","S"
"California,United States","89","lyt"
"Hartford,Connecticut,United States","879","polo"
"San Diego,California,United States","45454","utyr"
"Seattle,Washington,United States","uytr","69"
"United States","87","tree"
```

The  number of columns are not fixed and they may increase or decrease. Also I want to write to the CSV file without quotes and without escaping for the 'LocationList' column.

How to achieve the following in R? 
New to R any help is appreciated.

Comment: removing the NA as you implied makes the header info wrong. Do you want NA replaced by just black or space? and if you really want to remove NA , there are ways to do but I was wondering its use post-processing. Also if this is csv and desired output is also csv, can you not simply use any text processor to replace `NA,` by `""` (nothing), and also quotes `(")` by nothing

Comment: @Ananta The format is like 'NA,NA,United States' for 'LocationList' Column, I am not sure how it makes header information wrong?

Comment: oops, my bad. Then `df$LocationList<- gsub("NA,","", df$LocationList)` , and while `write.table` parameter `quote=FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
my.data <- read.table(text='LocationList,Identity,Category
                      "New York,New York,United States","42","S"
                      "NA,California,United States","89","lyt"
                      "Hartford,Connecticut,United States","879","polo"
                      "San Diego,California,United States","45454","utyr"
                      "Seattle,Washington,United States","uytr","69"
                      "NA,NA,United States","87","tree"', header=T, sep=",")
my.data$LocationList <- gsub("NA,", "", my.data$LocationList)
my.data
#                         LocationList Identity Category
# 1    New York,New York,United States       42        S
# 2           California,United States       89      lyt
# 3 Hartford,Connecticut,United States      879     polo
# 4 San Diego,California,United States    45454     utyr
# 5   Seattle,Washington,United States     uytr       69
# 6                      United States       87     tree
```

If you get rid of the quotes when you write to a conventional csv file, you will have trouble reading the data in later.  This is because you have commas already inside each value in the `LocationList` variable, so you would have commas both in the middle of fields and marking the break between fields.  You might try using `write.csv2()` instead, which will indicate new fields with a semicolon `;`.  You could use:

```
write.csv2(my.data, file="myFile.csv", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Which yields the following file:

```
LocationList;Identity;Category
New York,New York,United States;42;S
California,United States;89;lyt
Hartford,Connecticut,United States;879;polo
San Diego,California,United States;45454;utyr
Seattle,Washington,United States;uytr;69
United States;87;tree
```

---

(*I now notice that the values for* `Identity` *and* `Category` *for row* `5` *are presumably messed up. You may want to switch those before writing to file.*)

```
x             <- my.data[5, 2]
my.data[5, 2] <- my.data[5, 3]
my.data[5, 2] <- x
rm(x)
```

Comment: any reason to use `lapply` when it can be done by just `gsub("NA,", "", my.data$LocationList)`?

Comment: Good point, @Ananta. I changed that. I guess I just think `lapply()` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it has given me a good idea, still learning R and it's encouraging if some one answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you just want to replace the `NA,` with nothing. However, this is not the standard way to remove `NA` values.

Assuming `dat` is your data, use

```
dat$LocationList <- gsub("^(NA,)+", "", dat$LocationList)
```